# Map special characters to URL safe, readable versions

Tags: perl

i am looking for a mapping table or Perl module or anything else, which makes it possible to map characters to a URL safe version that is also readable.

I need to build URLs without any special characters. The base words are city names in their native language which means it can contain special characters from that language.

For example, when i have something like the polish city name 'łódź' i need to get a readable version like: 'lodz'

Comment: @TLP — URLs not HTML documents.

Comment: @Quentine Exactly. For example, when i have something like the polish city name 'łódź' i need to get a readable version like: 'lodz'.

Comment: Instead of doing "dumb" transliterations, it would be better to use a database of world city names that contains standardized ASCII representations. For example, `長谷` is the name of several places in Japan, but they are all read differently (`Hase`, `Nagayatsu`, `Nagatani`). There is no way to transliterate this accurately without knowing which specific location you're talking about.

Comment: Even if only one place was named `長谷`, `unidecode` is not likely to return something meaninfgul. You really need a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major browsers show and accept non-ASCII characters in the URL bar even if they need to be encoded during transmission.

For example,

```
http://.../city/Montr%C3%A9al
```

will appear as

```
http://.../city/Montréal
```

in the browser's URL bar. [[Test](https://www.google.com/?q=Montr%C3%A9al)]

But if you want to convert to a subset of ASCII, you'd start by using [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Unidecode)'s `unidecode`. Then you gotta decide what to do with the characters that must be escaped in URLs.

Comment: Hi, thx for this but that's not what i am looking for. Please have a look at my initial question again, i added an example.

Comment: You're the one who needs to read again.

Comment: Hehe, you are right, that will do it. The only thing missing are some German characters but i am able to map these manually as described in the Unidecode manual.